.net Blazor Radzen DialogService is not working
I have a blazor web application and I am trying to add Radzon. Radzen components all are working but when I am trying to add DialogService.Alert or
await DialogService.OpenAsync<DialogCardPage>("Dialog Card Page", new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {
        "LicId", "236a87aa-0dd6-483c-87f2-08dc9b660e4a"
    }
});

it doesn't show up
I did some research and I did all things the same with get starting radzon page.
<RadzenDialog />

I added radzendialog or components in mainLayout.razor too
I'm expecting at least something like this showing up


Deploy a Radzen application using the same template you're using.  It will work.  Compare the two and find out what you aren't doing different.   The few lines of code you've provided is very unlikely to tell us what you're doing wrong.

It doesn't show up probably because you have something wrong in DialogCardPage.
Please post DialogCardPage code, and the output from vs when you try to open the dialog.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
